# Click on a web element until a particular element is displayed

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a web element that when double-clicked, gives access to the dropdown. I am trying to use a do-while loop to achieve this but the web element needs one two or three double-click attempts to have dropdown being enabled.

```
do {
   ButtonAndMouseActions.doubleClickOnButton(driver,starSecurityHolderTypeValues.get(0));
} 
while (holderTypeDropdown.get(0).isDisplayed());
```

In `while` condition, the `holderTypeDropdown` is not displayed and it lands me in the holder type dropdown element not visible exception and my code is not executed further. I want to double-click on `starSecurityHolderTypeValues` until that `holderTypeDropdown is displayed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like you want to perform a double click on a button until a certain condition (in this case, the visibility of holderTypeDropdown) is met. You can achieve this by modifying your code slightly. Instead of using a `do-while loop`, you can use a `while loop` with a condition to check `if the holderTypeDropdown is not displayed.` If it's not displayed, perform the `double click;` otherwise, exit the loop.

```
int maxAttempts = 3;
int attemptCount = 0;

while (!holderTypeDropdown.get(0).isDisplayed() && attemptCount < maxAttempts) {
    ButtonAndMouseActions.doubleClickOnButton(driver, starSecurityHolderTypeValues.get(0));
    attemptCount++;
}

// Further code after the loop (e.g., interacting with the dropdown when it is displayed)
if (holderTypeDropdown.get(0).isDisplayed()) {
    // Your code to interact with the dropdown
} else {
    // Code to handle the case when the dropdown is still not displayed after max attempts
    System.out.println("Dropdown not displayed after " + maxAttempts + " attempts.");
}
```

In this code snippet, the loop will continue as long as `holderTypeDropdown` is not displayed and the number of attempts is less than the maximum allowed attempts (`maxAttempts`). If the dropdown becomes visible or the maximum attempts are reached, the loop will exit, and you can handle the scenario accordingly.